# How to access Java API within netbeans and another question

Tags: java, netbeans

I just have two specific questions that over the years I have never been able to figure out in netbeans.

1. How do I access the Java API documentation without having to use my web browser. It would be nice if I could have a window in netbeans of the Java API. Is this not possible? How do you normally access the API document? Note that I don't mean just access for the documentation for the current code (cntrl-space, I think)... I just mean for browsing.
2. Code completion will automatically generate right brackets (which I like). When this occurs, the cursor is still within the brackets. How do you jump out of the brackets without mousing? I know a command to move to the end of line, but sometimes the brackets aren't at the end of the line... it seems like there should be a way to just jump to the end of the autocompletion.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because these are read the documentation and search google for me questions.

Answer (score 0):

For 2) I honestly just use the right arrow.

Answer (score -1):

1. You can open the JavaDoc window
   with Window > Other > JavaDoc
2. Typing the closing bracket or
   parenthesis just puts you outside of
   the generated brackets

Comment: Window > Other > JavaDoc doesn't show the whole java API, at least not for me. It only shows doc for whatever the cursor is on. What I want is a browsable javadoc for the java API such as whats found at http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/